# how to install jackson-jaxrs-json-provider in centos 7

Tags: jackson, jax-rs, centos7

Platform : `CentOs 7`

I did a `yum install jackson` ...version installed is `1.9.4-7.el7`

I followed [this](http://pkgs.org/centos-7/centos-x86_64/jackson-1.9.4-7.el7.noarch.rpm.html) to install jackson packages.

I don't see a centOs specific rpm for `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider`

How do i get a jackson-jaxrs-json-provider rpm??

Answer (score 0):

jackson-jaxrs-json-provider is not a rpm but a Java library (see [the project page](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers))

To install, it depends how you configure your project, but for example using `maven` you would add the dependency as

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

If you just want to use the library, you can download it from [central](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/) and use it as any other Java library in your project

For rpm, you can have a look at the Fedora project rpm http://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=jackson2-jaxrs-json-provider (as the rpm is available for Fedora and the project you build is on Fedora, it is working) but it does not seem the rpm is available for centos

You can also check [here](https://javaworkshop.wordpress.com/2008/10/) how to build a rpm from Jar lib, long time I did not do it but should still be valid

Comment: I am not working with a maven project here. I get this error when I try to install dogtag using [this](http://pki.fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_Dogtag_10). It says **Error: Package: pki-base-10.2.0-6.el7.centos.noarch (/pki-base-10.2.0-6.el7.centos.noarch)
           Requires: jackson-jaxrs-json-provider**

Comment: I tried to manually add the jar under /usr/share/java/jackson/ but i dont see a  1.9.4-7 version from the link suggested [central](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/). All are 1.2+ versions.

Comment: seems dogtag is for Fedora and package available, you can try to use equivalent rpm for cent os (I believe its version F19 for centos 7) or try to build rpm from jar